# Cannot resolve method 'openFileOutput(java.lang.String,int)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-file

A night before, I implemented a code snippet in Android studio to access a file and write a string in a file.But some how I am not able to build it sucessfully. I don't know what is wrong with "openFileOutput()" method. 
I have already tried adding context before openFileOutput() method, but that doesn't work and if I am not wrong it must not.

Please help me. Here is the code part implementing that snippet.

```
package com.medaino.www.twitterapp;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;
import java.lang.String;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;


import android.view.View;
import android.content.Intent;


public class tweetlistactivity extends ListActivity {
   // private ListView tweetListView;
    private String[] stringArray ;
    private tweetaapter tweetItemArrayAdapter;



    public List<tweet> getDataForListView()
    {
        List<tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<tweet>();
        for ( int i = 0; i < 10; i++ )
        {
            tweet twt = new tweet();
            twt.setTitle("A nice header for Tweet # " +i);
            twt.setBody("Some random body text for the tweet # " +i);
            tweets.add(twt);

        }

        String FILENAME = "hello_file";
        String string = "hello world!";

        FileOutputStream fos = Context.openFileOutput(FILENAME,MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(string.getBytes());
        fos.close();

        return tweets;
    }





    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_tweetlistactivity);
        stringArray = new String[10];
        List<tweet> tweetlist = getDataForListView() ;
        tweetItemArrayAdapter = new tweetaapter(this, stringArray, tweetlist);
        setListAdapter(tweetItemArrayAdapter);

    }
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView list, View v, int position, long id)
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, tweet_detail.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_tweetlistactivity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

openFileOutput(); needs a Context. You are calling it in an ArrayAdapter. It should be:

```
// Define your context then use below code
context.openFileOutput();
```

Comment: thank you for reminding me that method was called inside an adapter. so just managed to change the implementation. but in this implementation i get another error saying non static method can't be referenced from a static context.

Comment: Update your source code. I will take a look. But please accept my answer above if it fixes your first problem.

Comment: FileOutputStream fos = Context.openFileOutput(FILENAME,MODE_PRIVATE); -> FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME,MODE_PRIVATE);

Comment: Still not works. I think I got it. I added everything to a try block and catch the exception. It then works

Comment: Congrats! Great to hear you passed it!

Comment: If my answer is right, can you give an acceptance to it?

Comment: This is your answer. So you are the only one can accept :)

Answer (score 0):

IT WORKS THIS WAY. WHEN I REMOVE THE CONTEXT WHICH IS NOT REQUIRED IN THIS CASE, I HAVE TO HANDLE THE FILE EXCEPTION.

```
try {                                                                  
  String FILENAME = "hello_file";                                       
  String string = "hello world!";                                       

  FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput(FILENAME, MODE_PRIVATE);        
  fos.write(string.getBytes());                                         
 } catch (Exception e) {                                                

     e.printStackTrace();                                               

}
```